# Simulator of microcontroller runs so slow in Proteus

Tags: avr, simulation, timer, proteus

I am trying to implement a simple program with ATmega128, which display numbers from 0 to F. The problem is when I set the delay time at 500ms, the simulation runs slower, at around 8 seconds for each digit.

[image]

Code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

unsigned char fnd[] = {0x3F, 0x06, 0x5B, 0x4F, 0x66, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0x27, 0x7F, 0x6F, 0x77, 0x7C, 0x39, 0x5E, 0x79, 0x71};

int main()
{
    DDRF = 0xFF;
    char i=0;
    while (1)
    {
        PORTF = fnd[i];
        _delay_ms(500);
        if (i==15)
        {
            i=0;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's all about Proteus' simulation engine. You can't do anything about it.

Comment: @RohatKılıç so are there any setting that I can change to make it improve the speed (no need to be precise)?

Comment: @Becker "you can't do anything about it", as Rohat says.

Comment: Decrease the delay and the "code" will run faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just realize you're simulating an immensely complex thing; this is simply a slow thing, and I don't think Proteus is a highly optimized-for-speed simulator – if anything, it's optimized for accuracy.

So, there's nothing you can do about it.